# Xpath returns result of complete list when performed on instance of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath

So I'm trying to apply xpath on a list of partially incomplete data, to find which fields are incomplete for each instance. Notably the data isn't just empty, the data field actually doesn't exist in them.
I've tried extracting the blocks to apply the operators on with "for product in products", but the xpath operations are still applied on the complete list. Is there a way to only get the xpath results of the individual element?

Here's my code:

```
products = response.xpath('//*[@class="mod-article-tile__content"]')
  for product in products:
      print(str(i) + ": " + self.clean_string(product.extract()) + "\n\n")

      name = product.xpath('//*[@class="mod-article-tile__title"]/text()').extract()
      amount = product.xpath('//*[@class="price price--50 price--right mod-article-tile__price"]/text()').extract()
      info = product.xpath('//*[@class="mod-article-tile__info"]/p/text()').extract()
     
      print("Product: " + name[0] + " : " + amount[0] + " : " + info[0])
```

By printing the div beforehand, I can see which elements of the data are absent, and can derive the expected result. However, at the moment name, amount and info all return a list containing each found instance in products, instead of searching only in product.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well-known issue which you can solve by just adding a dot at the beginning of XPath expression:

```
name = product.xpath('.//*[@class="mod-article-tile__title"]/text()').extract()
```

Note that I used `.//` instead of just `//`. That dot means that you want to start search *from context node* which is `product` in your case. Same for `amount` and `info`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I must say I didn't understand the official documentation very well, so that's probably it.